# Cannot deploy django api with heroku

Tags: django, heroku

When I try to deploy my Django rest API with Heroku I get this:

```
-----> Python app detected
       Using supported version of Python 3.6 (python-3.6.6)
-----> Installing python-3.6.6
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting Python==3.5.1 (from -r /tmp/build_eff222df1413c9c747fe9d073117baf7/requirements.txt (line 1))
         Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Python==3.5.1 (from -r /tmp/build_eff222df1413c9c747fe9d073117baf7/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
       No matching distribution found for Python==3.5.1 (from -r /tmp/build_eff222df1413c9c747fe9d073117baf7/requirements.txt (line 1))
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

How can I set my *requirements.txt* for this to work?, I used a virtual env, where I installed this:

```
django, 
djangorestframework, 
django-rest-auth, 
django-filter, 
django-cors-headers,
```

I'm using python 3.5, and django 2.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a common practice for deploying Python applications is to put the Python version into the **runtime.txt** file, not **requirements.txt**.

If you remove the line `python==3.5.0` from **requirements.txt** and create a file runtime.txt with the contents python-3.5.0, does your app stage properly?

Comment: You were right,  i just wasnt pushing the changes correctly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have put Python in your requirements.txt file. Don't do that.

If you really need to change the Python version from 3.6 to 3.5, you need to put that in runtime.txt, not requirements.txt. But there really shouldn't be any reason to do that at all. Stick with the default version.

Comment: This is the thing, i deleted python from requirements.txt, but the error still the same, it seems heroku doesnt update the changes,